# How can I stop my servo looping when my sensor doesn't detect movement?

Tags: servo, loop

I have this project with my Arduino UNO where I want my servo motor SG90 to go full speed to 180 degrees when the PIR sensor sends HIGH value and go slowly back to zero when the value is LOW.

I have this code working where the servo goes full speed back to zero:

```cpp
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo; //creates a servo object
int pos = 0; //variable to store servo position
//amount of time we give the sensor to calibrate(10-60 secs according to the datasheet)
int calibrationTime = 30;
//the time when the sensor outputs a low impulse
long unsigned int lowIn;
//the amount of milliseconds the sensor has to be low
//before we assume all motion has stopped
long unsigned int pause = 5000;
boolean lockLow = true;
boolean takeLowTime;
int pir = 12; //digital pin connected to the PIR's output
int pirPos = 13; //connects to the PIR's 5V pin

void setup() {
  myservo.attach(4); //attaches servo to pin 4
  Serial.begin(9600); //begins serial communication
  pinMode(pir, INPUT);
  pinMode(pirPos, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(pirPos, HIGH);
  //time for calibration
  
  Serial.println("calibrating sensor ");
  for (int i = 0; i < calibrationTime; i++) {
    Serial.print(calibrationTime - i);
    Serial.print("-");
    delay(1000);
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("done");
  
  //this waits until the PIR's output is low before ending setup
  while (digitalRead(pir) == HIGH) {
    delay(500);
  }
  
  Serial.print("SENSOR ACTIVE");
}

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(pir) == HIGH)
    myservo.write(180);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
  Serial.print("Motion detected!");

  if (digitalRead(pir) == LOW)
    myservo.write(0);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
  Serial.print("Motion ended!");
}
```

I'd like the servo to go slowly back to zero, so I tried this :

```cpp
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo; //creates a servo object
int pos = 0; //variable to store servo position
//amount of time we give the sensor to calibrate(10-60 secs according to the datasheet)
int calibrationTime = 30;
//the time when the sensor outputs a low impulse
long unsigned int lowIn;
//the amount of milliseconds the sensor has to be low
//before we assume all motion has stopped
long unsigned int pause = 5000;
boolean lockLow = true;
boolean takeLowTime;
int pir = 12; //digital pin connected to the PIR's output
int pirPos = 13; //connects to the PIR's 5V pin

void setup() {
  myservo.attach(4); //attaches servo to pin 4
  Serial.begin(9600); //begins serial communication
  pinMode(pir, INPUT);
  pinMode(pirPos, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(pirPos, HIGH);
  
  //time for calibration
  Serial.println("calibrating sensor ");
  for (int i = 0; i < calibrationTime; i++) {
    Serial.print(calibrationTime - i);
    Serial.print("-");
    delay(1000);
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("done");
  
  //this waits until the PIR's output is low before ending setup
  while (digitalRead(pir) == HIGH) {
    delay(500);
  }
  
  Serial.print("SENSOR ACTIVE");
}


void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(pir) == HIGH)
    myservo.write(180);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    
  Serial.print("Motion detected!");

  if (digitalRead(pir) == LOW)
    for (pos = 180; pos >= 0; pos -= 1) { // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees
      myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
      delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
    }
    
  Serial.print("Motion ended!");
}
```

The problem is with this code the servo does go slowly back to zero but then goes full speed back to 180 and again and again ....

Any idea? I'm a beginner in Arduino, so I assume it must not be that hard to figure out.
Thanks.

Comment: If `(digitalRead(pir) == LOW)` then you tell the servo to jump to 180 with this line: `for (pos = 180; pos >= 0; pos -= 1)`

Comment: I'd run your code through `Tools`/`Auto Format` in the IDE, which is something you should do before posting in the future, for the sanity of your readers, if not for your own.

Comment: Okay thanks for the tip guys !!

Answer (score 2):

Don't set the pos to 180 in the `(digitalRead(pir) == LOW)` branch if you do not want it to repeatedly jump up to 180 for as long as the condition is true.

```
void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(pir) == HIGH)
     pos = 180;
  myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    
  Serial.print("Motion detected!");

  if (digitalRead(pir) == LOW)
    for (; pos > 0; pos -= 1) { // decay to 0 degrees
      myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
      delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
    }
    
  Serial.print("Motion ended!");
}
```

Alternately, you could use `pos` as a state variable and simplify things:

```
void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(pir) == HIGH)
     pos = 180;
  elif (pos > 0 ){
     pos--;
     delay(15);
  }
  myservo.write(pos);
}
```

Comment: If `pir` is LOW, the OP's speed-controlled code will keep cycling between 180 and zero again and again.

Comment: "long as the condition is true" or maybe "as long as the input remains `LOW`".  I'm going to delete my previous comments above (and this one later), because with your good clarifications they're going to look more out of sync.

Comment: I pasted the code, works like a charm, thanks a lot to you two guys !!

Comment: It sounds like you should "accept" this answer.